# How would I get this function to choose from the deck?

Tags: python

```
import random


deck = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']

def dealer_total():
  dealer_total = 0
  while dealer_total < 16:
    dealer_card = random.choice(deck)
    deck.remove(dealer_card)
    if dealer_card == "one":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 1
    if dealer_card == "two":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 2
    if dealer_card == "three":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 3
    if dealer_card == "four":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 4
    if dealer_card == "five":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 5
    if dealer_card == "six":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 6
    if dealer_card == "seven":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 7
    if dealer_card == "eight":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 8
    if dealer_card == "nine":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 9
    if dealer_card == "ten" or dealer_card == "jack" or dealer_card == "queen" or dealer_card == "king":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 10
    if dealer_card == "ace":
      dealer_total = dealer_total + 11
  if dealer_total > 15:
    print(dealer_total)
  


def user_total(): 
  user_total = 0
  user_hit = input("Do you want to hit or stay? ")
  while user_hit.lower() == "hit":
    user_card = random.choice(deck)
    deck.remove(user_card)
    if user_card == "one":
      user_total = user_total + 1
    if user_card == "two":
      user_total = user_total + 2
    if user_card == "three":
      user_total = user_total + 3
    if user_card == "four":
      user_total = user_total + 4
    if user_card == "five":
      user_total = user_total + 5
    if user_card == "six":
      user_total = user_total + 6
    if user_card == "seven":
      user_total = user_total + 7
    if user_card == "eight":
      user_total = user_total + 8
    if user_card == "nine":
      user_total = user_total + 9
    if user_card == "ten" or user_card == "jack" or user_card == "queen" or user_card == "king":
      user_total = user_total + 10
    if user_card == "ace":
      user_total = user_total + 11
  print("Your total is", str(user_total) + ".")
  if user_total == 21:
    print("You win!")
  if user_total < 22 and user_hit == "stay":
    print(user_total)
  if user_total > 21:
    print("You busted!")

dealer_total()
user_total()
```

This is my code. Every time I run it, it says "Cannot choose from empty sequence" regarding the part where user_card is defined, even though it randomly chooses from the list fine for the defining of dealer_card. I'm also aware that there is a more concise way to do all of the if statements, I'm just unaware of how to do it since I'm a beginner coder. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you want to choose another random element from `deck` after you have already removed the last one.

Comment: In your own words, where you have `while user_hit.lower() == "hit":`, what is supposed to cause this to *stop* being true once it is true?

Comment: There are many issues with the code, yes, including the part where " there is a more concise way to do all of the if statements". This isn't a good place to get that kind of help, because this is *not a discussion forum* nor a tutoring website. You should try Reddit or Quora, or following an existing tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem here is that you ask for user input *before* the `while` loop, but then do not ask for new input inside the `while` loop so that conditions can change for exit.

```py
  user_hit = input("Do you want to hit or stay? ")
  while user_hit.lower() == "hit":
```

could be (limiting the amount of code change)

```py
  while input("Do you want to hit or stay? ").lower() == "hit":
```

followed by rest of the loop, since then the input will be requested every loop cycle.

I also suggest you use a dictionary to capture card values (why *is* there both a "one" and an "ace"?) like

```py
card_value = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3 # ... and so on
```

which will give you the chance later to use expressions like:

```py
  dealer_total += card_value[dealer_card]
```